# What part or kind of geoduck gives crunchy slender slices?

Tags: seafood

I purchased a few shucked geoducks  from Sunny Supermarket in Toronto fresh, but froze this one. I wanted to ask this question before preparing it.

[image]

After I purged the fresh shuck (not shown), I sliced it, but slices are these squat wedges in pics 1-2.

[image]

I wanted these skinny crunchy strips like pics 3-5.

[image]

Did I buy wrong kind of geoduck? Or wrong part?

[image]

Bibliography - Pics [1,2](http://peckthebeak.com/2015/03/geoduck-sashimi/), [3](http://marxfood.com/how-to-make-geoduck-sashimi/), [4](https://thedarkoside.com/2012/07/11/geoduck-sashimi/), [5](https://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/big-ts-seafood-market-bar-san-jose-3?select=oRmbW1DnEDVpdsntYWFUPg), [Geoduck anatomy picture](https://www.cuisinevault.com/geoduck-sashimi/).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you cut your geoduck “the wrong way” (to get the specific shape, that is). If you want crunch, you should use the syphon, so that was a hit already. For the wavy slices, I suggest watching the first recipe in [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NgNR-nAlWaw) by chef Hung Huynh. In short, he

- uses live geoduck
- quickly blanches the neck by immersing it in hot water
- peels the outer skin off and cuts the neck from the body. Then he
- slices the neck lengthwise and washes it in cold saltwater.

When he thinly **slices the halved necks at a bias**, he gets longish strips that curl “due to the contractions of the muscles”.

While you can still cut your frozen geoduck neck in thin slices, I doubt that they would curl the same way fresh do.